# How to manage many enemies all needing to reference the same movieclip asset

Tags: actionscript-3, memory

I am loading a .swf movie clip from a file to use as an enemy graphic in my game, but I will be creating many enemies. And I need to have many different movie clips that can be moved around for each enemy, but I am using Loader to load the asset from disk each time, and it is very apparent that flash keeps loading the movie clip asset.

How can I have my enemies all reference that same asset without loading the data for the movie clip asset each time? The MovieClip class has a x/y position it just feels that Loader should be loading an asset, that multiple clips can reference to conserve memory.

Comment: Well this is forcing us to guess a little bit. Some code would help. I recommend loading as many enemies as you will need at any one time, i.e. the maximum possible enemies at any given time, and then bring them onto the stage as needed and remove them from the stage as needed. Load them all at the beginning of the program or level or whatever so the assets are there and ready to use. Then recycle them as needed without having to use load again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to load the asset multiple times, it's a bad practice. You need to set the as-linkage in your asset like this:

[image]

and then you can load the asset into your current ApplicationDomain and use the getDefinitionByName method for getting the class definition. The very basic example:

```
    private static const ENEMY_CLASS:String = "game.assets.TheEnemy"; // full name from asset here
    public function Main()
    {
        const loader:Loader = new Loader();
        const url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("enemy.swf");
        // all the magic happens here, loaded class definitions will be available in the current ApplicationDomain 
        const loaderParams:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        loader.load(url, loaderParams);

    }

    private function onComplete(e:Event):void
    {
        const loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = e.target as LoaderInfo;
        if (loaderInfo.hasEventListener(Event.COMPLETE))
        {
            loaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        }
        const clazz:Class = getDefinitionByName(ENEMY_CLASS) as Class;

        const enemyOne:DisplayObject = new clazz();
        addChild(enemyOne);

        const enemyTwo:DisplayObject = new clazz();
        addChild(enemyTwo);
    }
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you Nbooo. This is what I was confused about. You have helped me so much!